# tflearn is not ported to tensorflow 0.12 on windows yet! Even with tensorflow 1.5

Tags: tensorflow, windows-10, tflearn

I currently have tensorflow-gpu 1.5, Python 3.5, and tflearn 0.3.2 installed however when I try running the sample code given [here](https://github.com/pannous/tensorflow-speech-recognition/blob/master/speaker_classifier_tflearn.py), I get this error.

[image]

I'm using anaconda 4.4.9 as well. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, there was an if statement in the actual code that was printing this error.

after running other tflearn sample code, I realized my tflearn is working fine.